# Moufiltr driver reenters on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, filter, driver, wdm, kmdf

I have built the moufiltr sample, installed on several OS. I found the re-entrant issue on Windows 8.1 platform if the USB device is USB 1.0, which is USB low speed device. The same driver can work on Windows 7 x32/x64 or USB 1.1 devices on Windows 8.1 x32/x64. I don't know why the moufiltr driver has the limitation on such the specific combination, USB low speed mouse + Windows 8.1. Could it be something I had missed?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

### The following is a log:

```
00000001 0.00000000
Mouse Filter Driver Sample - Driver Framework Edition.

00000002 0.00000247
Built Oct  1 2014 18:03:53 
00000003 0.00033270
Enter FilterEvtDeviceAdd 
00000004 0.00052762
Enter FilterEvtDeviceAdd
```

---

Driver is from [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Moufiltr-WDF-Version-fb57f5de).

Comment: The fact that FilterEvtDeviceAdd is called twice doesn't necessarily indicate that anything is wrong.  What is the actual problem?

Comment: It will block functionality of mouse. I am curious about what the windows kernel did on windows 8.1 only.